# Support for 5.25-inch floppy drives on IBM Thinkcentre 8187 KUR

Tags: bios, floppy-drive

I have an IBM ThinkCentre 8187KUR desktop system. It has a bay for 5.25-inch floppies but no support in the BIOS. My question is, can I put in a PCI card to support floppy drive access and run the 5.25-inch floppy drive on this system, theoretically bypassing the BIOS?

Comment: Are the connectors compatible?  The 5.25 floppies tend to use an edge connector:  3.5" uses a different sort.  Does the PCI card you are thinking of have a 5.25" compatible edge connector?

Comment: This may depend on the OS you are using: DOS very much interacts with the BIOS, other OSs like Linux have their own device detection. What is the intended OS?

Comment: Sorry, but that machine is barely 10 years old and effective still todays technology. Asking on a site for recent PC usage may be a bit more apropriate.

Comment: @Raffzahn Again, that might be depending on what he wants to do with this **14**-years old. DOS, CPM/86 or OS/2 might make the question on-topic.

Comment: @tofro If it would be a question about DOS,CP/M or OS/2 - as this would it make (mostly) on topic on any machine - so questions about M2 SSDs on a i7 just because some emulator is also stored there are? But it's a question about the PC Hardware in no relation to anything retro or outdated. . Also, it can't be 14 years, as the KUR model was introduced in 2006 (a 4 GHz P4 must be a Prescott or later, thus introduced 14 years ago, but it took some time until it got used, didn't it?). So *again* , as the question is *not* about anyof the topics you mentioned, it's clearly OT.

Comment: Who says the 5.25" bay is for floppy drive? From that time I'd say it is for CD-ROM (or DVD)

Comment: @cup the PCI card wouldn't need a 5.25"-compatible edge connector: the cable that you attach to it would. These are still available to buy online, even with the edge connector for 5.25" drives.

Comment: @Raffzahn, getting retro hardware (eg. a 5.25" floppy drive) to work with a modern computer strikes me as being on-topic.

Comment: @Mark 5.25s aren't retro as they are still available new. And f the new computer is at the center of a question (and here it is without any doubt), it's not retro at all.

Answer (score 1):

One hurdle in your way is finding a suitable PCI card.

In the early days of PCs, most interfaces such as serial ports, hard drive controllers and floppy disk controllers were on separate ISA expansion cards. In the 386 and 486 era, miniaturisation meant that many of these functions could be provided on a single expansion card, commonly known as a [Super-IO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_I/O) card. Manufacturers of SCSI interface cards, such as Adaptec, included floppy controllers on some of their cards, such as the [AHA-1542](https://adaptec.com/en-us/support/_eol/isa/aha-1542/). This meant that the user didn't need a separate card for their floppy drives.

By the times of the PCI bus, most motherboard manufacturers had started to include a Super-IO chip on the motherboard itself. There was thus no demand for PCI Super-IO expansion cards, and there would likewise be no need for SCSI interface manufacturers to include a duplicate floppy interface on their cards.

I've spent a few years looking for a PCI-based floppy solution, and have come to the conclusion that no such card was ever manufactured.

Alternative solutions include using a USB floppy controller such as the [FC5025](http://www.deviceside.com/fc5025.html), which can read (but not write) 5.25" floppies, or developing your own solution, combining a [PCI-ISA bridge](http://www.voxtechnologies.com/embedded-solutions/pc-104/ar-b104a) with an old ISA floppy controller card. Or getting an older motherboard that still supports 5.25" drives.